# Server to "notify" web service callers when another user makes a call

Tags: .net, web-services, chat, remoting, notify

Am making this card game with my brother for my family to play remotely. It’s kind of like hearts in Windows. Let’s assume it is hearts so that I don’t have to explain the boring rules of the game.

There will be 3 or more player and each player gets to throw a card on the floor during their turn.

I have a database and a class library with the business logic and reads/writes on the database.

Right now I have few functions:

- **New game**
- **Add players**
- **Start game**
- **Check game status** => Return what’s on the floor, what cards are on the callers hand, how many cards each of the opponent have, whose turn is it, who is the host, etc.
- **Make move** => User notifies the server that he wishes to use a certain card.

I have a web service that uses the class library and WebMethods to call each of the functions. The webpages/standalone exes can either use the class library directly or call the web service to use the function.

**I am struggling to come up with a design to “notify” other users that another player has performed an action.** Possible logics I have thought of:

- Call check game status every x seconds to see if things
- Call a web method “let me know if things changed” asynchronously with a call back function.

  - What if it times out?
  - What if a user leaves the game in the middle?

Please help me out with it.

Comment: If you're writing new code, then you should not be using ASMX services. You should be using WCF instead. Among many other features, WCF supports peer to peer and notifications trough duplex communications channels.

Comment: Looking back, this simple advice helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF duplex channels were designed for exactly this kind of scenario http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Polling the service would be acceptable as long as there isn't a large number of clients.  In addition, each client could send a "heartbeat" signal to the WS to indicate "yes I'm still connected".  In this manner you can detect disconnected clients.

If you prefer not to poll, you could look into push notifications:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465460.aspx